# How to repeat a non-capturing group "sub-query"?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

My Regex voodoo powers were not enough to beat this one up:

**Input:**

`x|a=1|b=2,y|c=3|d=4,`
*(bonus point if you allow me to drop the last comma)*

**Desired matches (and groups):**

`x|a=1|y=2` *(x, a, 1, y, 2)*
`y|c=3|d=4` *(y, c, 3, d, 4)*
*(bonus point if I can name every group)*

**My failing pattern:**

`(x|y|z)(?:\|(.+?)=(.+?))*,`

Basically, I want x, y or z and ALL the '|' separated pairs of 'this=that' afterwards.

**Matches (and groups) I'm getting:**

`x|a=1|b=2,` *(x, b, 2)*
`y|c=3|d=4,` *(y, d, 4)*

I have the comma in the matches, but that's no big deal, the main issue is that I'm only getting the last "sub-groups" for each match. Why is the first one ignored?

Comment: In .Net you can see repeated captures in Groups[?].Captures. Don't worry you already have correct regex and you can extract all data. Btw I think you can drop last comma

Comment: Damn, I didn't think of captures. I guess I'm gonna change of testing website...

Comment: Is this your own format? As @KovpaevAlexey says, if each subsequence starts with `[a-z]\|`, you already don't need the comma. But if it's your own format, I would use JSON or XML instead. Or go Full State Machine and write it myself. But that's basically never justified any more, sad to say.

Answer (score 1):

It's nice feature of .Net Regex to capture repeating groups and there are already pretty much answers on similar questions so I'll just put the link below

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11051948/1009099