# C++ RegEx repeated capturing groups

Tags: c++, regex

I am trying to parse strings of the form

`{{name1 | filter1|filter2 |filter3}}` into `(name1, filter1, filter2, filter3)`.

I have a RegEx:

```
static const regex r("\\{\\{\\s*([\\.\\w]+)(\\s*\\|\\s*[\\.\\w]+)*\\s*\\}\\}");
```

And I want to find *all* occurences of the second group, which marked with a Kleene star (...)*. The problem is that I can only find last occurrence of the group.

Instead I use the following RegEx:

```
static const regex r("\\{\\{\\s*([\\.\\w]+)((\\s*\\|\\s*[\\.\\w]+)*)\\s*\\}\\}");
```

To find the second capture group (whole substring `" | filter1|filter2 |filter3"`) and parse it with another RegEx.

How can it be done in C++?

The most similar question is here:
[Regex: Repeated capturing groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172643/regex-repeated-capturing-groups)

Comment: So, you want to replace `{{` by `(`, `}}` by `)` and `|` by `,`. Why such complex regex.

Comment: Сергей, did you consider using raw string literals? Backslashes are not regex best friends. Use `R"(PATTERN_HERE)"`. C++ std::regex does not support such a thing as C# CaptureCollection. Match the whole substring and then split/parse. It is easier. I'd use [`std::regex r(R"(\{\{([^}]*(?:}(?!})[^}]*)*)\}\})");`](https://ideone.com/T6F7D2).

Comment: Alternatively, you can use [Boost regex library `match_results::captures`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_33_1/libs/regex/doc/captures.html).

Comment: Thank you Wiktor. Boost captures seem like the thing I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add () around the "*" expression meant to match the second group.

```
(\s*\|\s*[\.\w]+)*
```

Here, the () group matches 1 instance of: SP | SP WORD
Even though the "*" matches zero or more instances of that.
Change it to:

```
((\s*\|\s*[\.\w]+)*)
```

Or, to be clear that the inner () isn't a tagged expression:

```
((?n:\s*\|\s*[\.\w]+)*)
```