# How to capture an indeterminate number of groups? Reg Ex

Tags: regex

I want to take a multiline string such as

```
(DateofAdmission04 DateofDischarge04 PatDateOfBirthC
= record_keydate1 record_keydate2 dob).
```

And capture each of the words, to then be paired with it's associated word on the other side of the equals, ultimately to produce the result (in this example)

```
(DateofAdmission04 = record_keydate1 
DateofDischarge04 = record_keydate2 
PatDateOfBirthC = dob).
```

(or similar). Is this possible using regex? Ideally as a general solution that would work on lists of any length.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5018487/regular-expression-with-variable-number-of-groups and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172643/regex-repeated-capturing-groups

Comment: I don't know any regex flavor that can capture an indeterminate number of groups. Though, using C# regex flavor, each capture will be stacked (have a look at [System.Text.RegularExpressions.Capture](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.capture.aspx)). But, as you only need pairing, using some split and join would probably be more readable and will do the job appropriately.

Comment: Thanks, I'm using RegEx in notepad++ to rewrite some SPSS syntax. I don't know enough about Java, or C++ but I think I could probably write a bit of Python to use split and join as you suggested!

Comment: [so] community is very active on Python. Feel free to ask if you're struggling with it.